# how to unhide an active div on mouse over using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i want to unhide a div on mouse over on it?

Presently , in my code(see below)  . On hover of a link,a advace search form is opening. And when users is moving their mouse from the url then the open form is closing. I want the form to be close only if the users move their mouse for the form.

Please suggest a solution for it.

```
          <html>
            <head>
              <style>
            div { background:#dad;
            font-weight:bold;
            font-size:16px;
            width: 400px;
            }
            </style>
              <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <a href="">Do advance Search</a>
              <div style="display: none">
                  <h2>Advance Search Form:</h2>
                  <form action="search.php"><br/>
                 <input type="text" name="isbn" placeholder="Enter Isbn"/><br/>
                <input type="text" name="isbn" placeholder=" Title  "/><br/>
                 <input type="text" name="isbn" placeholder="Enter Author First Name"/><br/>
                 <input type="text" name="isbn" placeholder="Enter author last name"/><br/>
                <input type="text" name="isbn" placeholder="Enter Isbn"/>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Search"/>
              </div>
            <script>
            $("a").hover(function () {
            $("div").toggle("slow");
            });
            </script>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For easier reference in the script, change:

```html
<div style="display: none">
```

To

```html
<div id="theForm" style="display:none">
```

And update your script to:

```js
$("a").hover(function () {
    $("#theForm").show("slow");
});
$("#theForm").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).hide("slow");
});​
```

This will make it toggle away the div when your mouse leaves it's box.

Reference [`jQuery.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)

Comment: Is it possible to do the same functionality on click and on mouse over?

Comment: Yes, you can change `$('a').hover` into `$('a').click` and you are good to go. But if you want the click to then toggle it on off you need also change the `.show("slow")` into `.toggle("slow")`. I updated the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffaNX/1/) for reference.

Comment: i mean "i want the same  functionality on both mouse over and on mouse click.

Comment: But if you have the same functionality on both hover and click you wont need the click since the hover already have showed it? I'm not quite following.

Comment: i want both event functionality for opening the form but for closing it i want only "close" button residing on the form.

Comment: For any close button, just add a [`jQuery.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event that does a `$('#theForm').hide("slow");` and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
$("a").mouseover(function() {
    $("div").show("slow");
});

$("div").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AHVR9/

Answer (score 0):

Check this **[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MNXcV/)**,Though i tweaked your code a bit

```
$("a").hover(function () {
            $("#searchfrm").show();
});

$("#searchfrm").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#searchfrm").hide();
});
```

Updated to add close button **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MNXcV/1/)**

2nd Update [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MNXcV/6/)

Comment: Thank you its working fine. Can you tell me another way like "if mouse over on the URL form will open save like above code but for closing the form users needs to click on the open form.... Currently your code is closing my form when i leave my mouse over the form.

Comment: @lovesangprince I have added a close button.pls check

Comment: Its working fine. But i do not want to close the form if users move their mouse out of the form. I want to close it only when they click that close button on the form.]

Comment: @lovesangprince It was easy, you should have removed .mouseleave function. anyway i have updated my answer

Comment: But it is opening only if i click on the url. i want to open the form in both (Onclick and on mouse over) events.

Comment: @lovesangprince check my 2nd update, added both mouseover and click functionality. but i wonder why you have already chosen your answer:-(

Comment: Now My form is better then before. Thanks. Why i chosen my answer because the title of my question is exactly matching with the answer which i chosen as correct.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $("a").mouseover(function() {
     $("div").toggle("slow");
 });
$("div").mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).hide("slow");
});
```